# How to automate data cleaning in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, data-cleaning

I have a .csv file with sales data for 13 different stores with columns:

- store #
- date
- manager-generated forecast
- actual sales

The data column is in the format "day - mm/dd/yyyy" and requires cleaning. I have code in Python (Jupyter Notebook) that cleans the data and splits it into a data set for each of the 13 stores - so the cleaning portion is taken care of.

The Python code removes the "day: from "day - mm/dd/yyyy" and converts it to a pd.to_datetime datatype. It also creates new features such as "dayofweek", "dayofmonth", and "dayofyear" from this pd.DateTime object.

The file is 721 KB on disk.

How can I automate the cleaning process so that when I upload future files to S3 with the same columnar format (just has more records of sales) the cleaning process is automated and the clean data is accessible by other AWS services?

The end goal is for the clean data to be available in Quick Sight and AWS SageMaker.

I am thinking to use AWS Glue integrated with Athena or maybe Lambda to clean the data when it is uploaded to S3, but I am not sure of the best approach.

Thanks.

Comment: AWS glue was my first thought. I think the main alternative would be a s3 event trigger to lambda.

Comment: I agree with @jordanm. Event triggered lambda is the best and siplest method for this size of data. Both Athena and Glue is probably overkill for that size of data.

Comment: Thank you guys jordanm and Trygvi Laksafoss

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to process an object in Amazon S3 as soon as it is uploaded, you could:

- Add an S3 Trigger to the S3 Bucket that invokes an AWS Lambda function
- The AWS Lambda function would be passed-in details of the object that triggered the event. The function could then read the object from S3, process the contents and write out a 'clean' version of the object to a different location (to avoid triggering it again!)
- Options: The Lambda function could then delete the incoming object since it is no longer required

Since you already have Python code, you could convert it into an AWS Lambda function while keeping the existing functionality. All that changes is reading the object Key from the incoming `event` message.